# Что-то наподобие border-radius

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли функция типа `border-radius`, но только не закруглять, а делать углы острыми.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? )

Comment: @КонстантинБашаркевич Вот так вот... http://prntscr.com/c5nb5i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.example {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #111;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 50% 100%, 0 70%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 50% 100%, 0 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Не работает пример в firefox